Closing tkinter window after a function is done executing
I'm trying to have a tkinter window open and have another function running in the background using the threading module, and I'd like to have the window close once the function is done executing. What I'm having trouble with, though, is figuring out if there is a way to use the after method to eventually close the window since I know it's time-dependent, and there isn't really a good way to estimate when the function would be done running. Would you guys happen to know of a way I could have the window open while the function is running and have it close once it's done?
Here's some sample code I wrote:
 win=Tk()
 thread_1=threading.Thread(target=function, args=(args,))
 thread_1.start()
 win.title("Collecting Results for {}".format(var))
 interface=mainWindow(win)
 interface.my_canvas.create_text(900/2, 600/3.50, text="Please wait as we are collecting results for {}".format(var), font=("Arial, 20"), fill="white")
 win.after(*this is where I could use help*,win.destroy)
 win.mainloop()


You may call win.event_generate("<Destroy>") at the end of function() to destroy the main window indirectly.

Here's a possible solution that uses a function I've called poll_thread_worker to periodically check if the thread worker is_alive (thanks to @acw1668 for reminding me)
When you click the Start button the target function will run in a separate thread for 5 seconds, then the app will exit.
The target function long_running_func uses sleep to simulate some work, but this is just an example
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep  # this is just for demonstration


def long_running_func() -> None:
    sleep(5)  # simulate some work that takes a while


def poll_thread_worker() -> None:
    if worker.is_alive():  # keep an eye on the thread
        # use 'after' to have the polling function call itself continuously
        root.after(100, poll_thread_worker)
    else:
        root.destroy()  # exit


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')

lbl = tk.Label(root, text='This is my main window')
lbl.pack()

# set up the thread to run the desired target function
worker = Thread(target=long_running_func)
# start the worker thread when the button is pressed (this is just an example)
btn = tk.Button(
    root,
    text='Start',
    # this lambda starts the thread, then starts the polling loop
    # (you could also put these calls into their own func and call that)
    command=lambda: [worker.start(), poll_thread_worker()],
)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()

Polling like this isn't the only way to handle this, but it's easy to implement and plays nicely with tkinter.

Looks great (+1) but why root.quit instead of root.destroy?

@TheLizzard Appreciated! And I don't have a good answer / rationale for that...I don't suppose it matters in this naïve example, but thinking on it, destroy might make more sense.

@JRiggles in most cases they act the same. But the difference is that the quit method simply stops the mainloop while your window and all its widgets remain in memory. This means that technically you can call the mainloop again to restore the window. When using the destroy command, the root and all its widgets will be destroyed and cannot be restored. To be honest, they are almost equal. However, it is usually "safer" to use the destroy command if you want to complete the program completely.

You don't need stop_event object as you can use worker.is_alive() to check whether the thread is still running inside poll_thread_worker().

@acw1668 That's a good point - I totally spaced on that! I'll make some edits.
